# Sorting Array of Std Class Objects by Custom Order (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I have an array of StdClass Objects that contain different Car Types (ex. Compact Car, Mid-Size Car, etc.). The array should be sorted in the following order:

- Economy Car
- Compact Car
- Mid-Size Car
- Standard-Size Car
- Full-Size Car
- Premium Car
- Luxury Car
- Standard-Size Convertible
- Mid-Size SUV
- Standard-Size SUV
- Full-Size SUV
- Minivan
- **The remaining cars in the array should then be sorted by lowest to highest price (Example: After Minivan, display Specialty Vehicle, Compact SUV, Full-Size Hybrid, Sports, and so on...).**

*I'm having a problem with sorting the remaining cars by price. I tried sorting by price first, and then the ordered list in the second usort but it's not working as expected. Any help would be appreciated. I posted a similar question earlier, but figured I'd repost a more organized version of the requirements.*

**Input Array:**

```
array (
  0 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Mid-Size SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'IFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '30.31',
  )),
  1 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Standard-Size SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'SFAR',
      1 => 'RFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '7',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '35.53',
  )),
  2 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Economy Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'ECAR',
      1 => 'EDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '2',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '37.21',
  )),
  3 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Specialty Vehicle',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'XXAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => false,
     'min_people' => false,
     'max_bags' => '',
     'min_bags' => '',
     'price' => '36.72',
  )),
  4 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Compact Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'CCAR',
      1 => 'CDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '3',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '37.21',
  )),
  5 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Mid-Size Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'ICAR',
      1 => 'IDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '39.46',
  )),
  6 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Standard-Size Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'SCAR',
      1 => 'SDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '41.77',
  )),
  7 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Minivan',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'MVAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '7',
     'min_people' => '7',
     'max_bags' => '5',
     'min_bags' => '2',
     'price' => '43.18',
  )),
  8 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Full-Size Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'FCAR',
      1 => 'FDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '43.50',
  )),
  9 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Compact SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'CFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '3',
     'min_bags' => '3',
     'price' => '46.42',
  )),
  10 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Full-Size Hybrid',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'FCAH',
    ),
     'max_people' => false,
     'min_people' => false,
     'max_bags' => '',
     'min_bags' => '',
     'price' => '48.00',
  )),
  11 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Standard-Size Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'STAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '48.39',
  )),
  12 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Premium Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'PCAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '2',
     'price' => '48.72',
  )),
  13 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Sports Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'XSAR',
      1 => 'SSAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '3',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '48.72',
  )),
  14 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Luxury Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'LCAR',
      1 => 'LDAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '5',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '52.16',
  )),
  15 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Full-Size SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'FFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '8',
     'min_people' => '7',
     'max_bags' => '4',
     'min_bags' => '2',
     'price' => '52.92',
  )),
  16 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Compact Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'CTAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '1',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '91.17',
  )),
  17 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Premium SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'PFAR',
      1 => 'UFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '7',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '5',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '92.64',
  )),
  18 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Specialty Car',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'XCAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '3',
     'min_bags' => '3',
     'price' => '94.42',
  )),
  19 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Mid-Size Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'ITAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '2',
     'min_bags' => '2',
     'price' => '97.98',
  )),
  20 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Full-Size Van',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'FVAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '15',
     'min_people' => '12',
     'max_bags' => '5',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '90.38',
  )),
  21 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Luxury SUV',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'LFAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '5',
     'min_people' => '5',
     'max_bags' => '3',
     'min_bags' => '3',
     'price' => '113.66',
  )),
  22 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Premium Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'PTAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '1',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '121.15',
  )),
  23 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Luxury Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'LTAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '1',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '129.01',
  )),
  24 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Premium Van',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'PVAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '15',
     'min_people' => '15',
     'max_bags' => '1',
     'min_bags' => '1',
     'price' => '159.49',
  )),
  25 => 
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'description' => 'Specialty Convertible',
     'codes' => 
    array (
      0 => 'XTAR',
    ),
     'max_people' => '4',
     'min_people' => '4',
     'max_bags' => '2',
     'min_bags' => '2',
     'price' => '307.64',
  )),
)
```

**Code:**

```
    $order = [
        'Economy Car' => 1,
        'Compact Car' => 2,
        'Mid-Size Car' => 3,
        'Standard-Size Car' => 4,
        'Full-Size Car' => 5,
        'Premium Car' => 6,
        'Luxury Car' => 7,
        'Standard-Size Convertible' => 8,
        'Mid-Size SUV' => 9,
        'Standard SUV' => 10,
        'Full-Size SUV' => 11,
        'Minivan' => 12
    ];

    usort($car_types,function($a, $b) {
        return $a->price == $b->price ? 0 : $a->price > $b->price;
    });

    usort($car_types, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
        $a_set = intval(isset($order[$a->description]));
        $b_set = intval(isset($order[$b->description]));

        return $a_set === $b_set && $a_set === 1
            ? $order[$a->description] - $order[$b->description]
            : $b_set - $a_set;
    });
```

**New Output:**

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Economy Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => ECAR
                [1] => EDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 2
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 37.21
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Compact Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => CCAR
                [1] => CDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 3
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 37.21
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Mid-Size Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => ICAR
                [1] => IDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 39.46
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Standard-Size Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => SCAR
                [1] => SDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 41.77
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Full-Size Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => FCAR
                [1] => FDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 43.50
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Premium Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => PCAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 2
        [price] => 48.72
    )

[6] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Luxury Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => LCAR
                [1] => LDAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 5
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 52.16
    )

[7] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Standard-Size Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => STAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 48.39
    )

[8] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Mid-Size SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => IFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 30.31
    )

[9] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Standard-Size SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => SFAR
                [1] => RFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 7
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 35.53
    )

[10] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Full-Size SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => FFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 8
        [min_people] => 7
        [max_bags] => 4
        [min_bags] => 2
        [price] => 52.92
    )

[11] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Minivan
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => MVAR
            )

        [max_people] => 7
        [min_people] => 7
        [max_bags] => 5
        [min_bags] => 2
        [price] => 43.18
    )

[12] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Specialty Vehicle
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => XXAR
            )

        [max_people] => 
        [min_people] => 
        [max_bags] => 
        [min_bags] => 
        [price] => 36.72
    )

[13] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Compact SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => CFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 3
        [min_bags] => 3
        [price] => 46.42
    )

[14] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Sports Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => XSAR
                [1] => SSAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 3
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 48.72
    )

[15] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Full-Size Hybrid
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => FCAH
            )

        [max_people] => 
        [min_people] => 
        [max_bags] => 
        [min_bags] => 
        [price] => 48.00
    )

[16] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Full-Size Van
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => FVAR
            )

        [max_people] => 15
        [min_people] => 12
        [max_bags] => 5
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 90.38
    )

[17] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Compact Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => CTAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 1
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 91.17
    )

[18] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Premium SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => PFAR
                [1] => UFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 7
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 5
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 92.64
    )

[19] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Specialty Car
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => XCAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 3
        [min_bags] => 3
        [price] => 94.42
    )

[20] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Mid-Size Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => ITAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 2
        [min_bags] => 2
        [price] => 97.98
    )

[21] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Luxury SUV
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => LFAR
            )

        [max_people] => 5
        [min_people] => 5
        [max_bags] => 3
        [min_bags] => 3
        [price] => 113.66
    )

[22] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Premium Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => PTAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 1
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 121.15
    )

[23] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Luxury Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => LTAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 1
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 129.01
    )

[24] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Premium Van
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => PVAR
            )

        [max_people] => 15
        [min_people] => 15
        [max_bags] => 1
        [min_bags] => 1
        [price] => 159.49
    )

[25] => stdClass Object
    (
        [description] => Specialty Convertible
        [codes] => Array
            (
                [0] => XTAR
            )

        [max_people] => 4
        [min_people] => 4
        [max_bags] => 2
        [min_bags] => 2
        [price] => 307.64
    )
)
```

Comment: The items collected by `order` should be removed from the original array, then the remaining items sorted by price. At this point you have two arrays, the two arrays should be merged.

Comment: Is this the result from a database query? If so, at least in MySQL you can do an `ORDER BY FIELD(field_name, 'VAl_1', 'VAL_2')`, which will usually be more efficient than doing so in PHP. I think it should also be possible to sort the rest by price.

Comment: Also, if you do absolutely have to do this in PHP and not SQL, in my experience a collection library like Laravel's collections or Knapsack will usually make something like this a lot less painful because it lets you chain the methods more easily than native arrays. As always YMMV and I would understand if OP didn't want the additional overhead.

Comment: Hey @MatthewDaly This info comes from an API, so unfortunately not using the database to store this info

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one call to `usort`.

First of all, you can also use `array_flip` to make it easier to manage the `$order` array. That way you don't have to type (or change) the number values:

```
$order = array_flip([
    'Economy Car',
    'Compact Car',
    'Mid-Size Car',
    'Standard-Size Car',
    'Full-Size Car',
    'Premium Car',
    'Luxury Car',
    'Standard-Size Convertible',
    'Mid-Size SUV',
    'Standard SUV',
    'Full-Size SUV',
    'Minivan'
]);
```

And the sorting itself:

```
usort($car_types, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $ret =  (isset($order[$a->description]) ? $order[$a->description] : count($order))
          - (isset($order[$b->description]) ? $order[$b->description] : count($order));
    return $ret ? $ret : ($a->price - $b->price) * 100;
});
```

The first assignment calculates the difference in order based on the *description* field. If no order is known, a default value of `count($order)` is taken instead (using the ternary operator): this way car types that are not in the `$order` array will be ordered after any car types that have an entry in `$order`. The `count` function works here assuming you have numbered the types starting with 0 (which is the case with `array_flip`), but you can use any great enough number instead.

The `return` statement then checks if the above value is different from zero, and if so returns it. If it is zero the difference in price (in cents) is returned. The value in cents is taken because the return value is expected to be an integer, not a float. As said in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

> **Caution:** Returning *non-integer* values from the comparison function, such as float, will result in an internal cast to integer of the callback's return value. So values such as 0.99 and 0.1 will both be cast to an integer value of 0, which will compare such values as equal.

Comment: This seems to be working 99.5%...there's only one car that doesn't seem to be sorted properly. See: http://prntscr.com/ghj2hu ...Thoughts?

Comment: Corrected: the difference returned by the sort callback must be at least 1 (or not more than -1), or else it will be considered 0.

Comment: I added an explanation to my answer.

Comment: While our answers are functionally identical I don't like the hardcoding of an arbitrary "maximum" value as there's a possibility of the `$order` array changing over time while the code remains static.

Comment: Well, to be fair, `PHP_INT_MAX` is also hardcoding. Anyway, although I find this a quite theoretical remark (999 is way higher than a practical number of car types), I have updated it to be dynamic, based on the size of the `$order` array.

Comment: True, but it's guaranteed to be the largest possible weight that could ever be assigned on any system.

Answer (score 0):

So just assign anything *not* in `$order` the maximum sorting weight, and then add a secondary price comparison if the cars have identical weights. This method is far more simple and only requires *one* sort operation.

```
usort($car_types, function($a, $b) use ($order) {
    $a_weight = key_exists($a->description, $order) ? $order[$a->description] : PHP_INT_MAX;
    $b_weight = key_exists($b->description, $order) ? $order[$b->description] : PHP_INT_MAX;

    if( $a_weight != $b_weight ) {
        return $a_weight - $b_weight;
    } else {
        return ( $a->price - $b->price ) * 100;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I still use both usorts for this? The one with the pricing first and then the one you provided?

Comment: No. As I said this accomplishes both tasks within a single sort.

Comment: This seems to be working 99.5%...there's only one car that doesn't seem to be sorted properly. See: http://prntscr.com/ghj2hu ...Thoughts?

Comment: Ahh, there's cents in the price. PHP doesn't round when converting to integer, it just drops the fractional portion. If you multiply the price by 100 you should get the result you want. [updating answer]

Comment: It's worth noting that if you're actually handling the exchange of real currency you should never use a floating point number for storing a quantity of money. Something like [moneyphp/money](https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money) will handle it safely and accurately.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Your answer also works!